# WordPress Navigation PHP Code

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m working on my website. I really like the theme I’m using but the post navigation (next/previous post) is fairly basic. It only displays the blog post titles (no thumbnail or excerpt etc). You can see an example at the bottom of this page:

http://www.telly.media/technology/test-post-seven/

The relevant bit of code seems to be in the single.php file:

```
<?php the_post_navigation(); ?>
```

Is there a way to change this so the links to next/previous posts look more like the boxes on my home page please:

http://www.telly.media

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to change navigation style?

Comment: Hi Nahid. I want the Next/Previous Post links to display in boxes (like the blog posts appear on the home page). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the functionality you want, but not just by using `<?php the_post_navigation(); ?>` function.

The `<?php the_post_navigation(); ?>` function displays the navigation links to next/previous post. That's why you are only seeing the blue links to those posts without any information such as the excerpt or the thumbnail.

On the other hand the boxes on your home page are probably created within the Wordpress loop. This means that Wordpress is looping throughout all available posts and for each one of them is displaying a box with the excerpt and thumbnail.

In order to achieve the functionality you desire, you will need to programatically extract the id's of the previous and the next post using the `get_adjacent_post()` function:

```
<?php
    $prev_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'your_taxonomy_slug' );
    if ( is_a( $prev_post, 'WP_Post' ) ){
        $prev_post_id = $prev_post->ID;
    }

    $next_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false, 'your_taxonomy_slug' );
    if ( is_a( $next_post, 'WP_Post' ) ){
        $next_post_id = $next_post->ID;
    }
?>
```

Then you will need to use `<?php $prev_post_obj = get_post($prev_post_id); ?>` and `<?php $next_post_obj = get_post($next_post_id); ?>` objects to get access to the fields of that post such as excerpt, title, permalink or thumbnail .etc For a full list of the of the fields you can access see this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/)'s first comment.

Comment: Thanks mate. Looks v complicated, but will give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem within many way, but you have to write some css style or use existed class that already use in your blog listing page. use this example instead of the_post_navigation() function.
example 1:

```
<div class="navigation">
   <p>
      <?php posts_nav_link('&#8734;','&laquo;&laquo;','&raquo;&raquo;'); ?>
   </p>
</div>
```

example 2:

```
<div class="navigation">
   <div class="alignleft">
       <?php previous_post_link('&laquo; &laquo; %','Toward The Past: ', 'yes');?>
   </div>
   <div class="alignright">
       <?php next_post_link('% &raquo; &raquo; ','Toward The Future: ', 'yes'); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

or check this link for more details https://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links

i hope it will solve Your problem